# What is the longest drought between a team's two titles?

Tags: trivia, records, championship

Is [the Chicago Cubs' victory after 108 years](http://www.usatoday.com/story/sports/mlb/columnist/bob-nightengale/2016/11/03/cubs-win-world-series-indians-game-7/93219032/) (1908 to 2016) the longest drought between a team's two titles in North American major sports leagues (NBA, NFL, NHL, MLB)?

Comment: At the moment, this almost has to be the record as none of the NBA, NFL nor NHL have been going for 108 years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The longest all-time droughts in each league are:

- MLB: [Chicago Cubs - 108 seasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Major_League_Baseball_franchise_postseason_droughts#Longest_World_Series_championship_droughts_through_history)
- NHL: [Toronto Maple Leafs - 48 seasons*](http://www.grayflannelsuit.net/blog/denied-the-10-longest-title-droughts-in-nhl-history)
- NBA: [Sacramento Kings - 65 seasons*](http://www.basketballinsiders.com/longest-nba-title-droughts/)
- NFL: [Arizona Cardinals - 68 seasons*](http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/news/here-are-the-five-longest-super-bowl-and-nfl-title-droughts/)

<sub>*active</sub>

Moreover, in the MLB, the White Sox (87 seasons), Red Sox (86 seasons), Phillies (77 seasons), and the Indians (68 seasons) had/have as long of a drought or longer than teams in other leagues.

Comment: I add: MLS: Chicago Fire - 18 seasons (active)

Comment: @JoeTaras If that were asked about, sure. "Chicago victory after 108 years (1908 to 2016) is the longest pause between two titles considering the major American sportleagues ***(NBA-NFL-NHL-MLB)***?"

Comment: Yes, but MLS President tells soccer is growing more and more. I've already upvoted your answer (very correct)

Comment: @JoeTaras That's great to hear. That still doesn't make it part of the question asked. (Thanks for the upvote...upvoted your comment for awareness).